# How to convert the describe table output list or map in groovy

Tags: groovy

How to convert the below output map or list in groovy

```
col_name,data_type,comment
"brand","string",""
"tactic_name","string",""
"tactic_id","string",""
"content_description","string",""
"id","bigint",""
"me","bigint",""
"npi","bigint",""
"fname","string",""
"lname","string",""
"addr1","string",""
"addr2","string",""
"city","string",""
"state","string",""
"zip","int",""
"event","string",""
"event_date","timestamp",""
"error_flag","string",""
"error_reason","string",""
"vendor","string",""
"year","int",""
"month","int",""
"",,
"# Partition Information",,
"# col_name            ","data_type           ","comment             "
"",,
"vendor","string",""
"year","int",""
"month","int",""**
```

- Need to separate the **partition** `columns` in separate `map` and **normal** columns in separate `map`.

Expected output:

```
[[brand,string],[...]]
```

Comment: expected output is not clear. explain in details please.

Comment: [brand:string,tactic_name:string, ........]

Comment: Need to ignore the double qoutes and extra comma values (,).

The list should contain the [columnName1:datatype1,columnName2:datatype2,.........columnNameN:datatypeN]
Need to creat the separate list for partition columns as well. [vendor:string,year:int,month:int]

Comment: Have you got the answer ?

Comment: Glad to hear. If you found this answer useful, you can accept and up-vote it. Read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

`CsvParser` is used to read the text. But your text needs some alteration before parsing it. So i did some `text processing` for fitting it into the `csv` format.

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:0.2')
import com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser

def csv = '''col_name,data_type,comment
"brand","string",""
"tactic_name","string",""
"tactic_id","string",""
"content_description","string",""
"id","bigint",""
"me","bigint",""
"npi","bigint",""
"fname","string",""
"lname","string",""
"addr1","string",""
"addr2","string",""
"city","string",""
"state","string",""
"zip","int",""
"event","string",""
"event_date","timestamp",""
"error_flag","string",""
"error_reason","string",""
"vendor","string",""
"year","int",""
"month","int",""
"",,
"# Partition Information",,
"# col_name            ","data_type           ","comment             "
"",,
"vendor","string",""
"year","int",""
"month","int",""**'''


def maptxt = csv.split('"# Partition Information",,')

def map1txt = maptxt[0].trim()

def map2txt = maptxt[1].trim().readLines().collect{ 

        it=it.replace('#','')

        it=it.replaceAll("\\s", "")

}.join('\n')

println getAsMap(map1txt)

println getAsMap(map2txt)



Map getAsMap (def txt)

{
    Map ret = [:]

    def data = new CsvParser().parse(txt)

    for (each in data){

        if(each.col_name) // empty keys are neglected.

        ret[each.col_name]=each.data_type
    }

    ret

}
```

your text has empty `col_name`. This code neglected that rows.

Comment: @KrishnaRam Glad to hear. If you found this answer useful, you can accept and up-vote it. Read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers